# getting full help from --help when using add_subparsers

Tags: python, argparse

I have this sample code:

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser

parser = ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument('config')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--verbose')
group.add_argument('--quiet')

commands = parser.add_subparsers()
command = commands.add_parser('upload')
command.add_argument('path')
command.add_argument('--url')
command = commands.add_parser('check')
group = command.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--md5')
group.add_argument('--path')

if __name__=='__main__':
    parser.parse_args()
```

Running this with --help gives:

```
usage: argparse_example.py [-h] [--verbose VERBOSE | --quiet QUIET]
                           config {upload,check} ...

positional arguments:
  config
  {upload,check}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --verbose VERBOSE
  --quiet QUIET
```

What I would like it to display is:

```
usage: argparse_example.py [-h] [--verbose VERBOSE | --quiet QUIET]
                           config {upload,check} ...

positional arguments:
  config
  {upload,check}

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --verbose VERBOSE
  --quiet QUIET

sub-commands:

upload [-h] [--url URL] path

    positional arguments:
      path

    optional arguments:
      -h, --help  show this help message and exit
      --url URL

check [-h] [--md5 MD5 | --path PATH]

    optional arguments:
      -h, --help   show this help message and exit
      --md5 MD5
      --path PATH
```

I did have a go at implementing a HelpFormatter subclass but got rapidly lost.

Does anyone have a workable implementation of such a subclass?

Comment: From a user perspective I don't think it is a good idea. Maybe you could show that only when `--verbose` is specified. Anyway I believe you can simply write a custom `HelpFormatter` that calls `format_help()` on the subparsers and then joins together the whole thing.

Comment: with subparser --help will display what you give on the line subparsers.add_parser(help="my help","my_sub_command") this will give you a summary-like that then you can query with ./foobar my_sub_command --help. I can provide a script where a deal with ~ 50 subcommands :)

Comment: @Bakuriu - for lots of verbose subcommands, I'd agree. For one or two short sub-commands. it's non-intuitive and more work to have to do `script.py config.ini upload --help`.

@FoxMaSk - I know how subcommands work, thanks.

To both you and subsequent readers, please don't try and tell me what I do and don't want. Please either provide help towards implementing the solution I've asked for or refrain from commenting. Thanks ;-)

Comment: You might be interested in [docopt](http://docopt.org/)

Comment: @Eric - Looked at it, it breaks down into too much complexity beyond the most trivial of cases, so sorry, no go.

Comment: @Bakuriu - Also *as I already said in the question* - I looked at implenting a `HelpFormatter` subclass but you should try implementing what you suggest before suggesting it - it's exactly the idea I had and ended up here as a result ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Is this close enough?  Apart from tweaking the `title` and `prog`, I am creating all the help strings, indenting the subparser ones, and combining them into string.

```
parser = ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')

parser.add_argument('config')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--verbose')
group.add_argument('--quiet')

commands = parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands')
command1 = commands.add_parser('upload',prog='upload')
command1.add_argument('path')
command1.add_argument('--url')
command2 = commands.add_parser('check',prog='check')
group = command2.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--md5')
group.add_argument('--path')

fmt1 = parser.format_help()
fmt2 = command1.format_help()
fmt2 = fmt2.replace('usage: ','')
fmt2 = fmt2.replace('\n','\n  ')
fmt3 = command2.format_help()
fmt3 = fmt3.replace('usage: ','')
fmt3 = fmt3.replace('\n','\n  ')
print('%s\n%s\n%s'%(fmt1,fmt2,fmt3))
```

which produces:

```
usage: PROG [-h] [--verbose VERBOSE | --quiet QUIET] config {upload,check} ...

positional arguments:
  config

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  --verbose VERBOSE
  --quiet QUIET

subcommands:
  {upload,check}

upload [-h] [--url URL] path

  positional arguments:
    path

  optional arguments:
    -h, --help  show this help message and exit
    --url URL

check [-h] [--md5 MD5 | --path PATH]

  optional arguments:
    -h, --help   show this help message and exit
    --md5 MD5
    --path PATH
```

Invoking this output is another issue.  Should it be produced by `parser.format_help()`, i.e. `-h`.  By another optional that behaves in the same way?  By a regular optional?